# Windows 11 - connect to shared printer, but it gives me error The specified network name is not available

Tags: networking, printer, windows-11

I have a shared printer on windows 10. Now I try to connect to it from windows 11 computer (it was on windows 10 before, but user clicked "update to windows 11" by accident). I get error "the specified network name is no longer available", and no error codes to begin with, like it was on win10. I tried:

1. Enabled SMB 1.0 completely
2. Disabled firewall and antivirus
3. Connect to a printer using a Create local port method - it gave me plain "Access denied" dialog
4. Turned off (Disabled) point and print restrictions policy via gpedit
5. Gave user Administration group
6. Used the following registry edit:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Print]
"RpcAuthnLevelPrivacyEnabled"=dword:00000000
```

Nothing helped.

What should I do next?

Comment: Have you tried accessing the device by IP address and not name?

Comment: Yes, I tried to enter IP address in a dialog box when connecting to shared printer, with same result

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Later I tried to reconnect a printer to win11 computer and share it from there, without success... Also I tried to connect to other shared printers in office from win11 computer, without success as well.

I have been looking for solution of similar issues. Although my issue seemed to be different, I tried solution from here: https://www.winhelponline.com/blog/printer-error-0x00000bc4-0x00000709-windows-11-22h2/ .

> Launch the Local Group Policy Editor (gpedit.msc).
> Go to the following section:
> Administrative Templates → Printers → Configure RPC connection settings. Select “RPC over named pipes” from the dropdown, and click OK.

There is another setting for disabling authentication of RPC calls.

That article was helpful for me.

Maybe I should really get a printserver device, that device seems useful

Comment: Yes. A print server as I noted in my answer is a very good thing to do

Answer (score 0):

> Enabled SMB 1.0 completely
> Used the following registry edit:

Windows 11 does not use SMB V1 and Registry Edits usually cause more harm than good.

SMB V1 is a huge security risk.

You need to upgrade your Printer to a network capable printer that is happy with SMB V2 and up.

You can also try using a Network Print Server:  Obtain and set up a network Print Server, attach the Epson Printer to the print server so it is now on your network. Install a modern Epson Driver on the computers - particularly Windows 11.  See if that works or if the printer is simply too old.

Comment: Company owner won't understand why should we discard a completely operational printer (the printer model is Epson L800, it's a bit old yes but really good). Thank you for insight about SMB 1.0. When we had Win 10 on that computer I did not enable SMB 1.0, it worked OK only with changed settings in Group Policy and registry edit. I started to have problems with that printer after Microsoft ruined network printing back in 2020-2021. My goal is to make that printer work over network

Comment: Old printers do not support modern operating systems so you will have to modernize the printer.

Comment: Unsecuring your operating systems so they get taken down in a simple hack will be vastly more expensive than a modern printer.

Comment: You might also try a Print Server and put the printer on your network. That may help (and may not). I amended my answer to accomodate this